# ITMS-90635 - Xcode not able to detect Mach-O format for main bundle

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, bitcode

I have searched it everywhere, Appstore validation is failing due to ITMS-90635, for all the threads on Stackoverflow Xcode is able to detect the Mac-o format for main and nested bundles, but for my specific case xcode is not able to tell which is the Mach-o format, while it can detect the Mach-O format for nested bundles:

> The main bundle Mach-O contains , while the nested bundle Mach-O
> contains arm64(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a
> platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting.

I have made sure ENABLE_BITCODE is set to NO for main as well as all the Cocoapods.